# Where do these methods belong to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I have a Service model, which has a method that queries a provider to get an array back:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
   def query
     return [1, 2, 3, 4]
   end
```

I don't store returned array in my ActiveRecord table.
Now, I would like to create a few methods, say, is_odd?, is_even?, that is *specific* to the returned array.

In terms of conventions, where should I store these methods? In a new class? new module?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap that data in a new class that has those methods and have your query method return an instance of the class.

This gives you a place to put related methods. Depending on your situation, it may also help you abstract away the internal representation of that piece of data.